# Opening a page by code in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Below code navigates to a page in `Swift`.
How can I run this code in `Xamarin.iOS` ?

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextView") as NextViewController
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the translation:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryBoard.FromName("Main",null);
var nextViewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("nextView") as NextViewController;
PresentViewController(nextViewController, true, null);
```

or if you are using async await:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryBoard.FromName("Main",null);
var nextViewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("nextView") as NextViewController;
await PresentViewControllerAsync(nextViewController, true);
```